# How to make a view resize/shorten itself when a new view appears on screen?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two views on screen, a Google Map fragment and a different custom fragment. Before the custom fragment appears on screen, the Google Map is fullscreen which is good. Once the new fragment appears at the bottom of the screen, I want to Google Map to be resized so it takes up only the available space not used by the new fragment.

ie. before new fragment

```
|----------------|
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|      Map       |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|----------------|
```

after new fragment

```
|----------------|
|                |
|                |
|                |
|      Map       |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|----------------| <-- Map ends here
|                |
|  New Fragment  |
|                |
|----------------|
```

XML file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.damia.placefinder.activities.MapsActivity" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/container_locations"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good time to use `LinearLayout` and the `layout_weight` attribute.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context="com.example.damia.placefinder.activities.MapsActivity"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_locations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If, for some reason, `LinearLayout` offends your sensibilities, you can also do it with `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/container_locations"
        tools:context="com.example.damia.placefinder.activities.MapsActivity"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_locations"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```